# Where I can find Chrome local history?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I'm using Chrome as the default browser on all my devices (laptop, desktop, tablet, smartphone, etc.), and on all of them I'm logged in with my Google account. It happens that I did't use my laptop so much in the last months, so I'm having difficulties accessing the laptop related history on Chrome, because when I go to history I found weeks and weeks of browsing history generated on the other devices. Is there a way to quickly access the local browsing history on a specific device?

Comment: which device & which OS?

Comment: It's a laptop with Linux (Ubuntu).